# Install Hadoop-1.4.6 on Windows via cygwin

Tags: java, hadoop, cygwin, hbase

I am currently attempting to install Hadoop-1.4.6 on Windows via cygwin, and have used the following link as reference.

http://hbase.apache.org/cygwin.html

After following the steps, there is still an error after attempting to start HBase

$ ./bin/start-hbase.sh

```
cygpath: can't convert empty path
2018-08-30 11:39:08,494 ERROR [main] util.Shell: Failed to locate the 
winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in 
the Hadoop binaries.
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBinPath(Shell.java:382)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:397)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:390)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:80)
        at 
org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getBoolean(Configuration.java:1437)
        at 
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.checkDefaultsVersion(HBaseConfigurati on.java:67)
            at 

  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.addHbaseResources(HBaseConfiguration.java:81)
            at 
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.create(HBaseConfiguration.java:96)
            at 
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.HBaseConfTool.main(HBaseConfTool.java:39)
    cygpath: can't convert empty path
    2018-08-30 11:39:11,591 ERROR [main] util.Shell: Failed to locate the 
    winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
    java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in 
    the Hadoop binaries.
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBinPath(Shell.java:382)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:397)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:390)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:80)
            at 
    org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getBoolean(Configuration.java:1437)
            at


org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.checkDefaultsVersion(HBaseConfiguration.java:67)
            at 

  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.addHbaseResources(HBaseConfiguration.java:81)
            at 
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.create(HBaseConfiguration.java:96)
            at 
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKServerTool.main(ZKServerTool.java:70)
    : Name or service not knownstname 127.0.0.1
    running master, logging to /usr/local/hbase-1.4.6/bin/../logs/hbase-DESKTOP- 
    BJTFB3C-master-DESKTOP-BJTFB3C.out
    : running regionserver, logging to /usr/local/hbase-1.4.6/bin/../logs/hbase- 
    DESKTOP-BJTFB3C-regionserver-DESKTOP-BJTFB3C.out
```

I am new to this installation and any explanation on the error log would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks

This are my details for start-hbase.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
#/**
# * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# * distributed with this work for additional information
# * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
# *
# *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
# *
# * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# * limitations under the License.
# */

# Modelled after $HADOOP_HOME/bin/start-hbase.sh.

# Start hadoop hbase daemons.
# Run this on master node.
usage="Usage: start-hbase.sh [--autostart-window-size <window size in hours>]\
      [--autostart-window-retry-limit <retry count limit for autostart>]\
      [autostart|start]"

bin=`dirname "${BASH_SOURCE-$0}"`
bin=`cd "$bin">/dev/null; pwd`

# default autostart args value indicating infinite window size and no retry limit
AUTOSTART_WINDOW_SIZE=0
AUTOSTART_WINDOW_RETRY_LIMIT=0

. "$bin"/hbase-config.sh

# start hbase daemons
errCode=$?
if [ $errCode -ne 0 ]
then
  exit $errCode
fi

if [ "$1" = "autostart" ]
then
  commandToRun="--autostart-window-size ${AUTOSTART_WINDOW_SIZE} --autostart-window-retry-limit ${AUTOSTART_WINDOW_RETRY_LIMIT} autostart"
else
  commandToRun="start"
fi

# HBASE-6504 - only take the first line of the output in case verbose gc is on
distMode=`$bin/hbase --config "$HBASE_CONF_DIR" org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.HBaseConfTool hbase.cluster.distributed | head -n 1`

if [ "$distMode" == 'false' ]
then
  "$bin"/hbase-daemon.sh --config "${HBASE_CONF_DIR}" $commandToRun master
else
  "$bin"/hbase-daemons.sh --config "${HBASE_CONF_DIR}" $commandToRun zookeeper
  "$bin"/hbase-daemon.sh --config "${HBASE_CONF_DIR}" $commandToRun master
  "$bin"/hbase-daemons.sh --config "${HBASE_CONF_DIR}" \
    --hosts "${HBASE_REGIONSERVERS}" $commandToRun regionserver
  "$bin"/hbase-daemons.sh --config "${HBASE_CONF_DIR}" \
    --hosts "${HBASE_BACKUP_MASTERS}" $commandToRun master-backup
fi
```

Comment: `cygpath: can't convert empty path` is very clear. I assume you have forgot to set some path variables and the script can not convert it. look inside `start-hbase.sh` for any usage of `cygpath` and verify any variable used.

Comment: Hi Matzeri, Thank you for reaching out.

Comment: Hadoop 2.x and above supports windows without Cygwin. I suggest not using a more than 6 year version of Hadoop. More importantly, refer to the Hadoop compatibility matrix in the Hbase documentation

Comment: Hi cricket_007. Thank you, i will look into that document and possibly use that. Do you mean HBase 2.x or Hadoop 2.x?